# C: Pass an typedef'd enum value to a function as a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, enums, function-pointers, void-pointers

**CONCEPT**

I have a library that runs some library code and then calls a user callback function with help of a function pointer. As a minimal example, it may be defined as follows:

```
function_typDef functions[] = {
    { READ_INT      , set_led_pwm, (void*)&pwm_value } };
     ^library func  ^user func    ^parameter
```

For anyone wondering what this is for: in this case it is used for a menu system. The library provides internal functions like changing menus, printing the current menu or reading user inputs. Every time the library is called, a user callback function may be run after the internal function, with a void-pointer passed as the parameter. The example above changes to input mode, reads a user input, converts it to an INT, stores this int at &pwm_value and then calls set_led_pwm((void*)&pwm_value).

**PROBLEM**

One of the main functions of a menu is to change between (sub)menus/menu pages. Menus are listed in a menu_menus_type, a typedef'd enum.

```
typedef enum menu_menus_type{
    MENU_MAIN,
    MENU_SUB1,
    MENU_COUNT
} menu_menus_type;
```

To change a menu, the same concept as shown above for the PWM value change shall be used to change the menu:

```
function_typDef functions[] = {
    { READ_INT      , set_led_pwm, (void*)&pwm_value },
    { CHANGE_MENU   , NULL       , (void*) MENU_SUB1 } };
     ^library func    ^user func   ^parameter
```

This works perfectly fine on the microcontroller I tested this on. However, *the program crashes during unit testing, due to a memory access violation*.

**QUESTIONS**

From what I understand, enum elements are just replaced by integer numbers during preprocessing. The typedef does not have any effect on this, it just tells the compiler to check if the identifier passed is part of the typedef'd enum. Correct?

If the above is correct, (void*)MENU_SUB1 should create a pointer to address 1. This is most likely not a valid address when used with an operating system, that will detect the violation?

When actually changing the menu, the pointer is dereferenced as `*(uint8_t*)pointer`. Shouldnt this return the value stored at address 1? That would be anything, but certainly not a valid ID for a menu. Why does this work on the microcontroller?

Comment: On modern systems memory is divided into pages. A page can be mapped to your process or not. If a page is *not* mapped to your process the process can't access memory in it. No user-space process will have the page "zero" (which include the address `0`, commonly the null pointer) mapped. Attempting to access any memory in an unmapped page will result in an error. Perhaps you should take some time to rethink how you use the values in the structure, especially you should not treat them as pointers unless you actually *know* that the value is a valid pointer?

Comment: Regarding ways to handle the value ("parameter" as you call it), perhaps is should really be a *parameter*, i.e. an *argument* that you pass to the function that is called? And then the called function could do what it want with the "parameter", including casting it back to `menu_menus_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wonder how I may pass a constant value taken from an enum to a function that expects a void pointer. Without storing it in an intermediate variable.
About the second comment: If i pass it as a parameter, then internal library functions and callback functions can not change the values of this parameter? (or you thinking of sending the address as a parameter and creating a pointer to that address?)

Comment: Don't cast integers into pointers, that's a smelly API design. Either pass values or pointers to variables containing values. Some oddball MCUs might trap if they fed get a misaligned pointer, even if you don't de-reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derreferencing you are using is wrong.

You should NOT derreference it.

In order to get the number, you should just cast it, the reverse way as you used in the `functions`array:

```
//Note that there are no pointer casting, nor derreference.
//All you want is to cast a "void pointer" (pointer) to an "int", so just do it:
int myNumber=(menu_menus_type)pointer;
```

If you derreference it, then you access the invalid memory and you have the crash then.

NOTE: You should cast to the ACTUAL type. You should not cast to an `int`, `uint8_t` or any other, since the compiler is free to use any suitable size for the `enums`, and if it choose a different integer type, then the cast could be incorrect.
The correct way is as shown in the example, using a cast directly to the enum type.

---

> the pointer is dereferenced as *(uint8_t*)pointer. Shouldnt this return the value stored at address 1?

No, you have not stored anything in the pointer. You have set the value of the pointer to point to address `1`. When derreferencing this address, you are trying to read the data in that address, which is not what you want.

You want to recover the value of the pointer, which is what you have set in the first place. So just a cast is enough.

---

> But why did this work on the microcontroller?

Because probably the microcontroller does not have any memory protection, while in a computer you have memory protection (given by the OS).

So, the microcontroller tries to access that pointer anad the (unexisting) memory protection allows it to do so. This is why the tests crashes.

But then, usually, in the low addresses of the microcontrollers is stored the interrupt table, so the addresses at 0x0 and up are usually valid in these devices, thus succeeding the read and not giving any error.

But the read value is not the value you are expecting. It would contain the data in the address 0x1, and not the value 0x1

> , the system would try to change to menu ID address of interrupt handler.

This is not correct either.

You are accessing the address "0x1".
Assuming a uC with 32 bit pointers, the pointer size is 4, so you are accessing an address beginning in the second byte, not the first (the first handler would be at address 0x0, the second at address 0x4, and so)...

And after accessing the address, you are casting it to `uint8_t*`, thus saying "at this address, there is contained a value of just one byte size. Then derreferencing it, so you are reading a single byte at address 0x1, which may be whatever, but not an address, just a byte.
Probably, by chance, it contains a 0x1 on it, so you have been lucky.

This is the definition of "Undefined Behaviour": anything can happen, even work correctly, but that case is just luck

Comment: I changed the derefencing to a simple cast, and the unit tests run fine now. I dunno what hit me while i was initially writing that. Ofc, if i input a number, i just use a number. But why did this work on the microcontroller?

Comment: @L.Heinrichs New edit trying to explain a bit more what happened.

Comment: I figured out why it behaved differently. There is a function changing the menu that was specifically designed for unit tests, to be able to change the menu without having the rest of the menu system being active. In this version, the value was dereferenced as described above, leading to memory access violations. The menu systems internals that would usually change the menu did not derefence but typecast the value, exactly what you pointed out was the right way to go.